# Ошибка php при работе с БД

Tags: php, pdo

```
Class Database
{
    public $db;
    public $name = "root";
    public $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Users;charset=UTF-8";
    public $password = "";

    public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->name, $this->password);
    }

    public function find_login($login) {
        $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT login FROM Users WHERE login =   {$login}');
        return $sql->rowCount();
    }

    public function find_mail($mail) {
        $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT login FROM Users WHERE mail = {$mail}');
        return $sql->rowCount();

    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\OpenServer\domains\hosting\Database.php on line 16

В отдельном файле без свойств и методов все работало, здесь же одна и та же ошибка, что это не объект. Как итог мне надо получить кол-во затронутых столбцов или же сам результат как факт. Пробовал через `$sql->fetch()`, та же ошибка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

и так

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT login FROM Users WHERE login = :login');
$sql->execute(array('login'=>$login));
return $sql->rowCount();
```

Comment: А вот это работает как часы. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

charset=UTF-8 на charset=utf8 Попробуй изменить, у меня из-за этого ошибка была

Comment: Нет, дело точно не в ней, я с mysqli запомнил, что в бд ее слитно пишут, а тут разные варианты пробовал.

Comment: Посмотри 1 ответ и попробуй, я все исправил:D